# How to set export printer add second page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

My screen split into crated two canvas Top and bottom .one is 2D and another 3D. now I attempted export printer. I get my image data (`twoDData` and `threeDDate`) both in add single page but I should need export printer 1st-page 2D image data, 2nd-page 3D image data set. How to do this?

```
this.exportPrint = function(){
    var twoDData = renderer2D.domElement.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
            var threeDData = renderer3D.domElement.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
            var printWin = window.open('','_blank','Print','top=0,left=100,height=600,width=600,toolbars=0,scrollbars=yes');
            printWin.document.open();
            printWin.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html>');
            printWin.document.write('<html>');
            printWin.document.write('<head><title>Construction</title></head>');
            printWin.document.write('<body>');
            printWin.document.write('<img src="' + twoDData +'"  onload=window.print();window.close();/>');   //twoDData
            printWin.document.write('<img src="' + threeDData +'"   onload=window.print();window.close();/>'); //threeDData 
            printWin.document.write('</body>');
            printWin.document.write('</html>');
            printWin.document.close();
            setInterval(function () {
                printWin.focus();
                printWin.print();
                printWin.close();
            }, 500);
};
```

How to set `twoDData` first page, `threeDData` in the second page? anything page break method?